# TikTok Lead Ads Integration for Salesforce - Permission security questions

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi, sfmcadmin

We recently installed [TikTok Lead Ads](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=e37a1c86-3ab9-4ad8-92d5-50222ea004d8) from the AppExchange.

Checking the installed packages in MC settings, I see that both `Read and Write` permissions are granted under the scope.

[image]

I also got this reply from SFMC support:

> Indeed, upon careful review of the screenshot, it's evident that both Read and Write permissions are granted under the specified scope.

But I want to be 100% sure of the meaning of this.

Does it mean TikTok has access with read and write permission to **all** of our Data Extensions?

Doesn't sound very secure...